# Is there a way to take an input that behaves like a file in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a task where I'm given an input of the format:

```
4
A CS 22 M
B ECE 23 M
C CS 23 F
D CS 22 F
```

as the user input from the command line. From this, we have to perform tasks like determine the number of male and female students, determine which department has the most students, etc. I have done this using awk with the input as a file. Is there any way to do this with a user input instead of a file?

Example of a command I used for a file (where the content in the file is in the same format):

```
numberofmales=$(awk -F ' ' '{print $4}' file.txt | grep M | wc -l)                     #list number of males
```

Comment: What happens when you omit the file name?

Comment: the program seems to hang without printing anything

Comment: @PESALADINNEPRANAVREDDY: if you remove the file argument many/most un*x style tools will read from standard-input instead (which seems to be what you want). However, many tools (such as `wc`) *only* output anything when their input has ended (i.e. they've been notified that they've reached the EOF). To do that when you enter text "manually" you usually use Ctrl-D on most consoles.

Comment: What they are trying to tell you is that this is how we interpret "doing this with user input". The knowledgeable user is expected to type in their data, and press ctrl-D on a new line when they are done. If you really mean something else, probably [edit] to explain what you actually mean.

Answer (score 0):

### Not Reproducible

It works fine for me, so your problem can't be reproduced with either GNU or BSD awk under Bash 5.0.18(1). With your posted code and file sample:

```
$ numberofmales=$(awk -F ' ' '{print $4}' file.txt | grep M | wc -l)  
$ echo $numberofmales 
2
```

Check to make sure you don't have problems in your input file, or elsewhere in your code.

Also, note that if you call awk without a file argument or input from a pipe, it tries to collect data from standard input. It may not actually be hanging; it's probably just waiting on end-of-file, which you can trigger with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

### Recommended Improvements

Even if your code works, it can be improved. Consider the following, which skips the unnecessary field-separator definition and performs all the actions of your pipeline within awk.

```
males=$(
    awk 'tolower($4)=="m" {count++}; END {print count}' file.txt
)
echo "$males"
```

Fewer moving parts are often easier to debug, and can often be more performant on large datasets. However, your mileage may vary.

### User Input

If you want to use user input rather than a file, you can use standard input to collect your data, and then pass it as a quoted argument to a function. For example:

```
count_males () {
    awk 'tolower($4)=="m" {count++}; END {print count}' <<< "$*"
}

echo "Enter data (CTRL-D when done):"
data=$(cat -)

# If at command prompt, wait until EOF above before
# pasting this line. Won't matter in scripts.
males=$(count_males "$data")
```

The result is now stored in *males*, and you can `echo "$males"` or make use of the variable in whatever other way you like.

Answer (score 0):

Bash indeed does not care whether a file handle is connected to standard input or to a file, and neither does Awk.

However, if you want to pass the same input to multiple Awk instances, it really does make sense to store it in a temporary file.

A better overall solution is to write a better Awk script so you only need to read the input once.

```sh
awk 'NF > 1 { ++a[$4] } END { for (g in a) print g, a[g] }'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/0ML7Xk

The `NF > 1` condition is to skip the silly first line. Probably don't put that information there in the first place and let Awk figure out how many lines there are; it's probably better at counting than you are anyway.